# Slack Bolt force close modal on AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api

I have a python app built on Slack's Bolt framework and deployed on AWS Lambda.

The flow is as such:

1. A user triggers a global shortcut which opens a modal
2. The modal has a small form where the user fills it and clicks submit.
3. The request is sent to AWS API gateway where it is then sent to my AWS Lambda
4. The lambda authenticates the user to [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) and invokes another lambda where the main logic is stored
5. When the lambda is invoked, the Bolt app's work is done.

The issue here is that after submission of a form, Slack demands that an acknowledgement is sent within 3 seconds.

I don't think my app is meeting this requirement because of the Okta authentication. Because of that, an error message is showing after submission and the form is not closing:

[image: slack-modal]

This message is showing even though the request is successfull (It is showing because i am not meeting the 3 seconds requirements)

I want the modal to close even if there are errors.

Below is my python code:

main.py

```
app = App(
    process_before_response=True,
    raise_error_for_unhandled_request=True
)

def main(event, context):

# * Log to cloudwatch
logging.info(f"Main function started with event:\n {event}")

# * Create a slack handler
slack_handler = SlackRequestHandler(app=app)

# * Return the slack handler
return slack_handler.handle(event, context)
```

After the main is executed, it goes to a middleware where i verify whether the token is valid:

```
@app.use
def middleware_verifications(payload, next):
    
    # * Log to Cloudwatch
    logging.info(f"Middleware `middleware_verifications` running with payload:\n {payload}")

    # * Get the request type
    type = payload["type"].lower() if 'type' in payload else "command"

    # * Verify if this is a modal
    # * Do not do anything if request is a modal
    if type != "modal":

        # * Verify if the verification token matches
        if not (TOKEN == payload['token']):
            raise BoltError(f'Error while verifying the slack token')

    # * Goes to the next middleware
    next()
```

The view_submission is then sent to the function below:

```
# * View submissions goes here * #
```

@app.view("patching_scheduler_submit")
@authenticate([TG.IT_PLATFORM.value])
def view_patching_scheduler(ack, body, client, view):

```
# * Log event to cloudwatch
logging.info(f"View patching scheduler body: {body}")

# * Acknowledge request
ack(
    {
        "response_action": "clear"
    }
)

# * Get the user id
user = body["user"]

# *** Extract input values
patching_type = view['state']['values']['ptype']['multi_static_select-action']['selected_option']['value']
patching_start_date = view['state']['values']['pstartdate']['datepicker-action']['selected_date']
patching_end_date = view['state']['values']['penddate']['datepicker-action']['selected_date']  
patching_start_time = view['state']['values']['pstarttime']['timepicker-action']['selected_time']  
patching_end_time = view['state']['values']['pendtime']['timepicker-action']['selected_time']  

# * Log to cloudwatch
logging.info(f"patching_type: {patching_type}")
logging.info(f"patching_start_date: {patching_start_date}")
logging.info(f"patching_end_date: {patching_end_date}")
logging.info(f"patching_start_time: {patching_start_time}")
logging.info(f"patching_end_time: {patching_end_time}")

# * Invoke the lambda integration
PatchingScheduler(
    username=user['username'],
    patching_type=patching_type,
    patching_start_date=patching_start_date,
    patching_end_date=patching_end_date,
    patching_start_time=patching_start_time,
    patching_end_time=patching_end_time
).call_integration()

# * Send a message to the user
client.chat_postMessage(channel=user["id"], text="Patching scheduler in progress.")

returnobject={
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "",
    "response_action": "clear"
}
return returnobject
```

The decorator `@authenticate([TG.IT_PLATFORM.value])` is where the code takes time because it has to check the user against the `Okta API` which takes more than 3 seconds.

I also tried to remove the decorator and use the `authenticate` inside the function after the `ack()` but it still gave me the error on the modal:

```
@app.view("patching_scheduler_submit")
def view_patching_scheduler(ack, body, client, view):

    # * Log event to cloudwatch
    logging.info(f"View patching scheduler body: {body}")

    # * Acknowledge request
    ack(
        {
            "response_action": "clear"
        }
    )

    # * Get the user id
    user = body["user"]

    # Authenticate
    authenticate([TG.IT_PLATFORM.value])
```

The modal doesn't close. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Hi, Did you try sending an acknowledgement on receiving request? https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#acknowledge

Comment: https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#shortcuts   Shortcuts must be acknowledged with ack() to inform Slack that your app has received the request.

Comment: I did. Check the code

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the `processBeforeResponse` option to true?
It is recommended for FaaS

[image]

Comment: Yes i did put that in the `app()` config

Comment: can you send also the configuration ? if you have a seperate receiver it will not pull it directly from the app config you need it in the receiver config

Comment: I have editted the question to adde the `app()` config

Comment: ok that one looks good - have you also tried if it works locally? just to ensure it isn't an issue with aws lambda

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure that the interactivity event is an API Gateway url set as a trigger for a Lambda function where that Lambda drops the event object on an SQS que and immediately returns a status code 200 response (empty body) (closing the modal). Then that SQS que can be a trigger for another lambda that does the processing. This will omit the timeout and provide a huge flexibility benefit. [interactivity events are called when the submit button is clicked on the modal]

You need to format your data with action_ids and use a reduce function to get the action ids so that you can extract the form data.